# How do I run selenium-side-runner headless at the command line?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, command-line, headless

I'm using selenium-side-runner v 3.11.0 on Mac Mojave.  I would like to run tests in a headless Chrome browser, however, adding "--headless" doesn't seem to work.  When I run

```
PATH=/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/dev/:$PATH selenium-side-runner --headless -c "browserName=chrome" myTest.side
```

The test is still opening in a Chrome window that I already have running on my machine. (I would like the tests to run fresh each time, unaffected by any open Chrome windows I may be using for myself).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below command .It should work . [Source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/300#issuecomment-513862256)

Tested on widnows 10 + Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) .

```
D:\example>selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--headless,--nogpu] browserName=chrome" Testing.side
```

Link for information on goog:chromeOptions  [Issue 1786: Feature request: change chromeOptions to goog:chromeOptions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1786)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. Lot of the existing documentation and information is not correct on this module

Comment: @TarunLalwani Just edited the answer and tested on windows 10 + version 75 . It works

Comment: Worked fine now!